# How can I make the mdl tooltip to stick to the icon?

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am using the mdl tooltip on a an material icon, what can I do to make the tooltip stick to the icon.

Normally the tooltip looks like this but when scrolled the tooltip is on a wrong div:

[image]

But upon scroll it looks like this:

[image]

Code:
HTML

```
    <div>
   <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="headerLogoLinkField" onchange="updateHeaderLogoLink()" >
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="headerLogoLinkField">Header Logo Link...</label>
   </div>
   <div id="header-logo-reset" class="icon material-icons toinline">replay</div>
   <div class="mdl-tooltip toinline" for="header-logo-reset">
      Reset To Default
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toinline { 
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Put your absolute position tooltip into a relative position parent and it will works I suppose

Comment: Will try that, I am new to CSS so I will have to look that up.

Comment: Will make a fiddle for you in answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said in the comments, to avoid this kind of behavior you can put your absolute position tooltip **inside** a relative parent.

Here's a fiddle for example with content text above and below the input text. When you hover your input and scroll, you can see the tooltip stay at the same place and don't move.

> HTML part

```
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="headerLogoLinkField" onchange="updateHeaderLogoLink()" >
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="headerLogoLinkField">Header Logo Link...</label>
    <div class="mdl-tooltip toinline" for="header-logo-reset">
      Reset To Default
    </div>
  </div>
```

> CSS Part

```
.toinline { 
  background: #333; 
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  top: -30px; 
  left: 50px;
}

.mdl-textfield:hover .toinline { 
  display: block; 
}

.mdl-textfield { position: relative; }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnLx6zjx/2/)

Comment: For some reason I cannot see the icon now.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't seem to be working for me. This might look lame but I marked it as solved because I thought it will work and I had to leave the work for some urgent reason but when I implemented this, it doesn't seem to be working. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be using [Material Design Lite (MDL)](https://getmdl.io). MDL has its own tooltip component that doesn't seem to work with scrolling out of the box. This solution doesn't work because it sets things like `left` on the tooltip, so in this case adding `position: absolute` seems to make things worse.